# Where I can Find Path of resources *.jar in JNLP?

Tags: java, jnlp

i download a java app webstart.JNLP . After i opened in notepad, i found it listed some resource as below, i think, for the app to be able to load, those *.jar must be locate some where in my pc. Where can i find the path to *.jar ? does any one help ideas ?

```
    <jar href="sax2.jar"/>
    <jar href="soap.jar"/>
    <jar href="sslava.jar"/>
    <jar href="winpack-3.6.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="secprops-prodny.jar"/>
```

Comment: You don't need it. Just load the contents as resources: this is the whole idea. You don't need to know where the .jar file is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The location can be found by:

   1. Open the [Java Control Panel](http://pscode.org/player.jnlp)
   2. (Close the Java Cache Viewer that opens over the top of that)
   3. On the General Tab, Temporary Internet Files section, click Settings.
   4. The location will be shown under ..Location.
2. Below the Location section of that dialog is a Disk Space section.  If Select the compression level for JAR files: is set to None (the default), there will be no Jars, just class files and other loose resources.

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux system you'll find the jar cache in ~/.java/deployment/cache/javaws/  The jars will be in a directory based on the url the jar was downloaded from.

On Windows (XP) system this same folder should be in C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment

For Vista and Win 7 I assume its similar, but I don't know where the "Application Data" folder is located in those OSes.