# Where does JNLP store jar files

Tags: jnlp

Where does a JNLP downloaded program actually store the jar files on the local machine? The desktop link under XP points to a directory under C:\JNLP_cache which contains a few files none of which are the physical jar files of the application. Since the program can be started when there is no link to the original download site, they're on the local system somewhere?

Regards

Comment: See [Where I can Find Path of resources *.jar in JNLP ??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962457/where-i-can-find-path-of-resources-jar-in-jnlp). On my system these files are strangely named but they are there (check the `.idx` file which contains the original file name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the jar files cached for Java Web Start/JNLP applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517350/where-is-the-jar-files-cached-for-java-web-start-jnlp-applications)