# Why is JRE version different in Browser Applet than it is using Java -version?

Tags: java, applet, jvm, version

Using cmd.exe:

```
C:\Users\voo82361>java -version<br/>
java version "1.7.0_21"<br/>
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)<br/>
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

But when verify version here http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp I get:

[image: verifying java version]

How is this possible?? I know I have two installations of Java but I thought these two methods would reflect the same JRE.

**Edit:**
It was explained in the duplicate question that the browser's Java version may be different due to a plugin. I had checked this before writing this question but I can't say it was clear. Below are the plugins installed in IE firstly those loaded, and those shown as all (in the manage-addons window).

Loaded:
[image: loaded addons]

All:
[image: all addons]

From this what I inferred still did not add up since the loaded runtime I would expect is Java SE Runtime Evironment 7 Update 21 as shown. Which of these is actually used or is there a way for the applet to specify which version to use?

Comment: 1) Open the JCP according to the instructions on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3963909/418556) 2) But at 'point (3)' go to the Java tab and activate the View button. 3) Ensure all the older versions are unchecked, and the new version is checked.

Comment: I've done this but both JREs shown are unchecked, I have 1.7.0_21 and 1.6.0_34 showing but no 1.6.0_21 which I would expect given what the Java verification tool says.

Comment: Is that in the System or User tab you were looking?  Check them both.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, both. In system only the 1.7 edition is listed but it is too unchecked.