# Where are JAR files downloaded after launching JNLP through Web Start

Tags: java, jnlp

Where are the JAR files downloaded after launching a JNLP through Web Start?

I have searched in my home directory in `appdata/local...`, but it is showing `.jnlp` file instead of `.jar`.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962457/where-i-can-find-path-of-resources-jar-in-jnlp

Answer (score 4):

just run the below command and then select resources in the tool

javaws -viewer

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned "appdata" I assume you are running webstart on windows - on an other OS things obviously are different.

The location of the downloaded JARs has changed some versions ago, but current versions use `C:\Users\<your userid>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache` (at least on my Windows 7 machine, but I think it should be the same for newer Windows versions).

Note that under the `cache`-directory there is an additional folder structure and also note that the JAR-files are not saved under the same name that they are stored on the server but using some computed value - and not even using the `.jar`-extension (e.g. one of our JAR-files is stored as `6cb5c740-6bb35453-1.0-`).

Comment: thanks for your reply.In my case after cache directory there is a folder with 6.0 and inside that there are s many folders with numbers but every folder is empty......there is no computed value...